# Entity Framework Code First Stored Proc Incorrect Syntax / Must Declare Scalar Varible

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Working on getting a stored procedure to execute from a web app. I can verify that the values are being populated like the should but I either get one of two errors.

Here is the relevant code, I have also looked around and tried a few different solutions, just stuck as to why it's not working.

```
// incorrect syntax near newCompany - have tried with both the parameter1 and parameter1.Value, parameter2 and parameter2.Value
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany);
    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany);
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany @NewCompany", parameter1, parameter2);
}

// Message = "Must declare the scalar variable \"@OldCompany\"." - have tried with both the parameter1 and parameter1.Value, parameter2 and parameter2.Value
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany);
    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany);

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany, @NewCompany", parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TransferRecords]
    @OldCompany int,
    @NewCompany int
AS
BEGIN
    -- delete existing records from new company
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE CompanyID = @NewCompany

    -- copy records from old company to new new company
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([ID], [CompanyID], [City], [State], [Priority])
        SELECT NEWID(), @NewCompany, City, State, Priority
        FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
        WHERE CompanyID = @OldCompany

    -- reset record pages for both new and old companies
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- deletes Dynamic Content Cache for both new and old companies
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Table]
    WHERE CompanyID IN (@OldCompany, @NewCompany) 
      AND (ContentKey LIKE '%-generic-service-page' OR
           ContentKey LIKE '%-item-custom-service-page' OR
           ContentKey LIKE '%-about-page')

    -- deletes contents to so they will be regenerated
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
    WHERE CompanyID IN (@OldCompany, @NewCompany) 
      AND IsCityPage = 1
END
```

Web UI markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h2 style="text-align:center"> This copy Records from old Company to new Company</h2>
    <div class="centered" style="width:400px">
    @Html.TextBox("oldCompany", id, new { onkeyup = "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')", watermark = "Old Company #", @class = "watermark", style = "display:inline-block;" })
    @Html.TextBox("newCompany", String.Empty, new { onkeyup = "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')", watermark = "New Company #", @class = "watermark", style = "display:inline-block;" })
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Copy" class="right orangebutton" style="position:absolute;left:62%;" />
    </div>
}
```

I got it to work properly by changing the following

```
// Original
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany);
    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany);
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany, @NewCompany", parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

to:

```
// Working
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
   var @params = new SqlParameter[]
   {
       new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany),
       new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany)
   };
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany, @NewCompany", @params);
}
```

If any has any insight as to why this method worked over the other original one I would love to find out. Thanks all who replied.

Comment: How about 1) explicitly using `EXEC`, and 2) explaining why you're giving the source for the stored procedure `usp_TransferRecords` when you're trying to call `usp_CopyRecord`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo should have been calling usp_TransferRecords instead of copy records

Comment: What does `EXEC usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany = @OldCompany, @NewCompany = @NewCompany` yield? And how about `EXEC usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany = ?, @NewCompany = ?` (The latter should not be necessary, but hey.)

Comment: just the amount of records that deleted / transferred
(0 rows affected) // deleted
(8 rows affected) // transferred

   exec dbo.usp_TranferRercords @oldCompany = 1234,@newCompany = 5678

Comment: No, I mean, change the execution strings in your code to read that and see if you get a different error message (or working code). Knowing that the statements work in a query window is also interesting, but not the point. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Message = "Must declare the scalar variable \"@OldCompany\"." - have tried with both the parameter1 and parameter1.Value, parameter2 and parameter2.Value
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany);
    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany);
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_CopyRecord @OldCompany, @NewCompany", parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

Your error message tells you the problem.

> "Must declare the scalar variable \"@OldCompany\"."

```
"@OldCompany" != "OldCompany"
```

Comment: I figured that one was because of the comma between the parameters here "usp_CopyRecord @OldCompany, @NewCompany"

Comment: possibly.  I'm not familiar with `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand` syntax.  But the `SqlParameter`s definitely need the `@` in their names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what eventually

```
// Working
public virtual int usp_TransferRecords(int oldCompany, int newCompany)
{
   var @params = new SqlParameter[]
   {
       new SqlParameter("OldCompany", oldCompany),
       new SqlParameter("NewCompany", newCompany)
   };
   return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("usp_TransferRecords @OldCompany, @NewCompany", @params);
}
```