# EF6 Syntax error when getting stored procedure results with parameter

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I don't understand why I'm getting a syntax error when this line of code executes:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Kitti_getProductGroupDetail_Result>("Kitti_getProductGroupDetail @ProductGroupId", @params);
```

Here is the whole method:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<Kitti_getProductGroupDetail_Result> Kitti_getProductGroupDetail(Guid ProductGroupId)
 {
     var @params = new SqlParameter[]
     {
            new SqlParameter("ProductGroupId", ProductGroupId)
     };

     return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Kitti_getProductGroupDetail_Result>("Kitti_getProductGroupDetail @ProductGroupId", @params);
}
```

Here is the calling method:

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProductDetail> getProductDetailsFromSP(Guid ProductGroupId)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductDetail> productDetailList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductDetail>();

    using (var context = new EFDbContext())
    {
        var result = context.Kitti_getProductGroupDetail(ProductGroupId);

        foreach (Kitti_getProductGroupDetail_Result res in result)
        {
             ProductDetail productDetail = new ProductDetail();
             productDetail.ProductId = res.productid;
             productDetail.SizeId = res.sizeid;
             productDetail.SizeDescription = res.sizedescription;
             productDetail.SizeRank = res.sizerank;
             productDetail.ColorId = res.colorid;
             productDetail.ColorDescription = res.colordescription;
             productDetail.ColorRank = res.colorrank;
             productDetail.QuantityRemainingInStock = res.quantityremaininginstock;
             productDetail.ProductGroupId = res.productgroupid;
             productDetail.ProductGroupName = "ProductGroupName is currently not in the stored procedure or in EF";
             productDetail.Description = res.description;

             productDetailList.Add(productDetail);
         }
     }

     return productDetailList;
 }
```

The result object:

```
public partial class Kitti_getProductGroupDetail_Result
{
    public System.Guid productid { get; set; }
    public System.Guid productgroupid { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> colorid { get; set; }
    public string colordescription { get; set; }
    public int colorrank { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> sizeid { get; set; }
    public string sizedescription { get; set; }
    public int sizerank { get; set; }
    public int quantityremaininginstock { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string imagesrc { get; set; }
}
```

Finally here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Kitti_getProductGroupDetail] 
@ProductGroupId uniqueidentifier



-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT product.ProductId as 'productid', product.ProductGroupId as 'productgroupid', product.[Description] as 'description'
, product.Price as 'price', product.ColorId as 'colorid', color.ColorDescription as 'colordescription', color.ColorRank as 'colorrank', 
product.SizeId as 'sizeid', size.SizeDescription as 'sizedescription', size.SizeRank as 'sizerank', product.QuantityRemainingInStock as 'quantityremaininginstock',
product.Name as 'productname', product.ProductImageSrc as 'imagesrc'
FROM dbo.Product product
INNER JOIN dbo.Color color
    on color.ColorId = product.ColorId
INNER JOIN dbo.Size size
    on size.SizeId = product.SizeId
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductGroup productgroup
    on productgroup.ProductGroupId = product.ProductGroupId
WHERE product.ProductGroupId = @ProductGroupId
AND product.QuantityRemainingInStock > 0
```

ProductGroupId is definitely getting populated. What doesn't EF like about my code? I have a similar method that does not require a parameter to execute the stored procedure - it works fine

```
 // this works just fine
    public virtual ObjectResult<Kitti_getProductDetailsAndCategory_Result> Kitti_getProductDetailsAndCategory()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Kitti_getProductDetailsAndCategory_Result>("Kitti_getProductDetailsAndCategory");

        //ExecuteFunction changed to ExecuteStoreQuery
    }
```

stack trace:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Kitti_getProductGroupDetail'. 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'Kitti_getProductGroupDetail'.

Source Error:

Line 40:    };
Line 41: 
Line 42:             return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery("Kitti_getProductGroupDetail @ProductGroupId", @params);
Line 43:         }
Line 44:

Source File:  C:\Concrete\EFDbContext.cs    Line:  42

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'Kitti_getProductGroupDetail'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2444082
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5775560
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +409
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2127
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +911
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +14
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +402
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +266
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__68() +44
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__67() +167
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +190
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +462
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +83
   KittiCutieFashion.Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext.Kitti_getProductGroupDetail(Guid ProductGroupId) in C:\KittiCutieFashion\KittiCutieFashion.Domain\Concrete\EFDbContext.cs:42
   KittiCutieFashion.Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext.getProductDetailsFromSP(Guid ProductGroupId) in C:\KittiCutieFashion\KittiCutieFashion.Domain\Concrete\EFDbContext.cs:82
   KittiCutieFashion.Domain.Concrete.EFProductDetailRepository.get_ProductDetail() in C:\KittiCutieFashion\KittiCutieFashion.Domain\Concrete\EFProductDetailRepository.cs:33
   KittiCutieFashion.WebUI.Controllers.ProductDetailController.ProductDetailView(String returnUrl) in C:\KittiCutieFashion\KittiCutieFashion.WebUI\Controllers\ProductDetailController.cs:43
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748493
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0

The version of sql server I am using happens to be 2005 not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Shoudn't the parameter name start with `@`, e.g. `new SqlParameter("@ProductGroupId", ProductGroupId)`?

Comment: Makes sense to me. However that change had no affect on the error. I did not include that symbol because a different example did not include that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986574/entity-framework-code-first-stored-proc-incorrect-syntax-must-declare-scalar-v

Comment: Try adding `EXEC` before stored procedure name, possibly that behavior only exist when using SP with parameters (certain hidden commands may executed before running the SP).

Comment: Tetsuya that worked!!! Thank you so much :D  U da man!

Comment: I never saw any examples online where you have to add EXEC in front like that. Crazy.

Comment: Feel free to add your comment as an answer to this I will mark as the solution.